# the meaning of "o instanceof Point point" in overrided equals function

Tags: java

I have Point class as the following code:

```
public class Point {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Point point)) return false;
        return x == point.x && y == point.y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
}
```

The equals function is generated by IntelliJ, which can also accept a subclass of Point as a parameter. But I don't understand the meaning of `if (!(o instanceof Point point))`. Why is there `point` after `Point`, and how is `point` defined in the equals function?

Comment: [Pattern matching for `instanceof`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html)

Comment: does this: if (!(o instanceof Point point)) actually compile? My guess, you meant to type: if (!(o instanceof Point))

Comment: @Stultuske They didn't "mean to type" anything, because it was generated by IntelliJ. The declaration of the `point` variable is necessary for the line below that. See [the part of the JEP starting "The flow scoping analysis..."](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394)

Comment: I'm still getting accustomed to the fact that the scope of the pattern variable can extend beyond the statement it's declared in.

Comment: @Michael which version was this added in?

Comment: @Stultuske It was introduced as a preview feature in version 14: https://openjdk.org/jeps/305

Answer (score 4):

This is called "Pattern matching for instanceof".

I am going to assume you know the previous syntax which would be.

```
if( !(o instanceof Point) ) return;

Point point = (Point)o;

return x == point.x && y == point.y;
```

As of java 16 there is a new syntax that is supposed to be a bit more concise.

```
if( !(o instanceof Point point) ) return;

return x == point.x && y == point.y;
```

Instead of casting and creating a local variable, you can declare the variable within the instanceof statement.

The scope of the pattern variable is described as "flow scoping" in [JEP 394](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394) which can be a bit non-intuitive. [Pattern Matching for instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html) has more examples.

Comment: I knew the feature but hadn't realized that its scoping rules are different, TIL! But the link you provided doesn't mention "flow scoping" by that name. Do you have a source for that name? Especially for new features I'd like to be very specific and "correct" when I talk about them.

Comment: @JoachimSauer [JEP 394](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394) mentions this term a few times.